# sliding an html form with jquery doesn't work with defined controls

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html form with `<nav>` tag. The form is the following ;

```
<section class="dropinput">
      <form id="add_task_form" class="addTaskForm" action="">
        <input type="text" id="add_task_name" class="addTaskInputFirst">
        <input type="submit" id="add_task_button" class="addTaskBtn">
        <nav>
          <input type="text" id="add_task_date" class="addTaskInputFirst imptdetail">
          <p class="date"></p>
          <input type="text" id="add_task_location" class="addTaskInputFirst imptdetail">
          <p class="location"></p>
        </nav>
      </form>
</section>
```

The control of nav tag rule is the following;

- if all of the text fields are empty and the mouse is out the form, then the text fields    inside the `<nav> </nav>` will be slided up.

I have the following .js file to do that;

```
$('#add_task_form').focusout(function(){

if( (!$('#add_task_name').val()) && (!$('#add_task_date').val()) && (!$('#add_task_date').val()) )
    {
        $('.dropinput nav').slideUp(300);
    }

});
```

I think I got the right code but it doesn't work. The nav area opens correctly when I click the first field but after I move to other text fields, it slides up if I don't enter anything in the `add_task_name` field.

Can you help me to solve this issue ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the sliding works for you with none of the rules/conditions.

Then check each of your conditions to see if they are the values you expect them to be.

Comment: sliding works correctly. but it doesn't behave according to the conditions in jquery

Answer (score 0):

When you are moving to the other input fields from the first field, you are essentially doing a *focusout* (from the form) and that is why the fadeout is happenning.

The following code satisfies your nav tag rule on page load but not sure if this is what you want...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#add_task_form input:focus").length == 0) {
        $("nav").slideUp(300);
    } else {
        // do what you need to do
    }
});
```